# C# Winforms handle unhandled exceptions

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, exception

I want to catch all unhandled exceptions in my application. so I used this code to catch all the unhandled exceptions:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        SaveEx(e.Exception);
        Application.Exit();
    }

    static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        SaveEx((Exception)e.ExceptionObject);
        Application.Exit();
    }

    static void SaveEx(Exception ex)
    {
        bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\AppLogs\"));

        if (!exists)
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\AppLogs\"));


        String filePath = @"C:\AppLogs\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-dd-M--HH-mm-ss") + ".txt";

        String log = "===========Start=============\r\n";

        log += "Error Message: " + ex.Message + "\r\n";
        log += "Stack Trace: " + ex.StackTrace + "\r\n";

        log += "===========End=============";

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, log);
    }
}
```

I tried to raise these exceptions with a divide in 0:

on main thread it's work perfect:

```
int t = 0;
int r = 5 / t;
```

But when i try to do it inside a `Thread`:

```
 Thread thread = new Thread(delegate()
 {
      int t = 0;
      int r = 5 / t;
 });
 thread.Start();
```

The `CurrentDomain_UnhandledException` function got called but it keeps calling the `int r = 5 / t;` row in my code so I have a loop of exceptions. Any idea what can be the problem? the thread is called only once.

Comment: How do you call `thread.Start()`, I mean where?

Comment: Application.Exit() is the not the correct way to terminate the app, that only sets the wheels in motion.  You have no wheels left when the car smashed into the wall.  Use Environment.Exit() instead.

Comment: @AliBahrami I used it inside a button click event

Comment: @HansPassant it's not because of that, I already removed it and I still have this problem.

Comment: Speculating what "I already removed it" might mean is not very useful when you can show us.  Guidance was to *replace* it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change Application `UnhandledExceptionMode` 
 to `UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException` to make things works correctly. Microsoft already wrote a very good article about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.setunhandledexceptionmode?view=netframework-4.8).

I tried to simulate your work. Everything worked well, take a look on my example.

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        // Set the unhandled exception mode to force all Windows Forms errors to go through
        // our handler.
        Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);

        // Add the event handler for handling UI thread exceptions to the event.
        Application.ThreadException += Application_ThreadException;

        // Add the event handler for handling non-UI thread exceptions to the event. 
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    private static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.Message, "Application_ThreadException");
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        var exception = e.ExceptionObject as Exception;
        MessageBox.Show(exception.Message, "CurrentDomain_UnhandledException");
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

So, if we raise an exception inside a thread like below:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var thread = new Thread(delegate () {
            throw new DivideByZeroException();
        });

        thread.Start();
    }
```

1. `button1_Click` is fired.
2. thread get started and raises a `DividedByZeroException`.
3. `CurrentDomain_UnhandledException` catches the exception, shows the message and closes the app

Comment: is it not required to unsubscribe the static event handlers in order to prevent memory leak? see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0